# scp to remote server permission denied

Tags: ssh, permissions, scp, mac-osx-server

I try to copy files to a remote server (OSXServer) using scp. I have 2 user accounts on that server with what I thought the exact same settings. Now I tried the copying files into the respective home folder (every user has one home folder) on the server.
This works for one account but not the other.
How can I find out why this is happening and maybe change the settings so that I can copy stuff with both accounts?(I have administrative access with both accounts according to the workgroup manager)

Edit:

It is a pure permission problem as "touch" does not work either with the one user account.

Edit2:

```
chown -R "usrname" "folder"
```

also gives me permission denied.

Edit3:
To top the weirdness:
Everywhere else except of the home directory it works fine...

Edit4:
I have no idea why the server was set up in such way but now I could change the permissions logging in as root...

Comment: What are the permissions on the non-working users' home folder? (check with `ls -ld ~username`)

Comment: "nobody" how can I change that? Basically every new user I create has "nobody" in his home directory.

Comment: "nobody" refers to ownerships. @mtak was asking about permissions (i.e. read, write, and execute bits). Can you please provide the output to the command he specified?

Answer (score -1):

Log in using your super user and set work location to your other account and give some group permission to your weird account.

Comment: That's just masking the actual problem, not fixing it. The real problem is getting the correct owner settings on the other account.

Comment: The other account is nobody bro, to fix it you can use other super user to set up the correct owner to the othr account.

Comment: That's what I said. Adding group permissions is not correct.

Comment: May be adding group permission is not correct. So, do you have any better idea how to solve that ?

Comment: What I said in the first comment. Go read it.